# Fetching object_id for all pictures of facebook friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the object_id of all pictures that my friends has on facebook.

This is the method  I use that I believe should work fine:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=[YOURTOKEN]&query=SELECT object_id FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid FROM friend WHERE uid1=me )) ORDER BY created DESC
```

My problem is that I only retrieve 5108 object_id's , thats nowhere close to the total number of pictures that all of my friend has. 
Is there a restriction from facebook ? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to the end of your query. So to get the first 1000 photos, you would have `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0`, then for the next group `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1001` and so on.

You are also using a legacy endpoint. You should be using the newer one:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=[QUERY]&access_token=[TOKEN]
```

Comment: Thanks! The new graph api in combination with offset and limit works.